# How to multiply two select values SQL

Tags: sql, select

I would like to calculate daily profit in my project, and for that I need to multiply two columns from different tables.

Table ORDER:

```
ID       int,
DATE     date
```

Table DISH:

```
ID        int,
NAME      string,
PRICE     decimal
```

Table BELONGS:

```
ID         int,
DISH_ID    int,
ORDER_ID   int,
QUANTITY   int (that is number of ordered pieces of specified dish)
```

To calculate daily profit I should multiply column PRICE from DISH and QUANTITY from BELONG for every dish in every order.

Can you help me to write sql query?
Thank you :)

Comment: you should add what you tried..

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the expected output looks like given some sample data.

Comment: I am using SQL server management studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
Select o.date, sum(d.PRICE * b.QUANTITY) as dailyrevenue
from order o join
     belong b
     on o.id = b.order_id join
     dish d
     on d.ID = b.dish_id
group by o.date;
```

Note that this calculating *revenue*, not profit.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me. But I have one more question. How to add all dailyrevenue results? When your solution is executed I got table with two colums: DATE and dailyrevenue(one dailyrevenue represents cost of one order).

Comment: I solved problem, thank you :) 
My solution:
Select sum(d.PRICE * b.QUANTITY) as dailyrevenue
from order o join
     belong b
     on o.id = b.order_id join
     dish d
     on d.ID = b.dish_id
where cast(o.date as date)=@input_date;

Answer (score 1):

Try below query

```
Select d.PRICE * b.QUANTITY as DailyProfit
from DISH d join
     BELONG b
     on d.ID = b.DISH_ID
```